# Key Event In java Error

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, keylistener

Why am I getting this error, which is bruh.setLocation(bruh.x + 2, bruh.y); The errors are the x and y variables. How would I fix this issue?

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("bruh.png"));
        bruh = ii.getImage();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
        g2d.drawImage(bruh, x, y, this);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            bruh.setLocation(bruh.x + 2, bruh.y);
        }
    }    

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {                
        }    
    }    

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace for the error?  I'd need that before I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `bruh` is an [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) and Image does not have a setLocation method

Comment: Incidentally, `Image` also lacks the `x` and `y` fields.